# Behat [ERROR 1871] This element is not expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, behat

When I am running `behat` in my project, I get the following output:

```
[mattias:~/projects/resecond]$ behat                                                                   (staging✱)
Feature: User
  In order to personalize the app
  I want to give users the ability to create an
  account

  Scenario: Finding a specific user                              # app/tests/acceptance/User.feature:6
    Given I request "users/dd40ee60-98d3-11e4-a625-07e5e99a99e6"
    Then I get a "200" response




  [Symfony\Component\Translation\Exception\InvalidResourceException]
  [ERROR 1871] Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}target': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}context-group, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}count-group, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}note, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}alt-trans, ##other{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}* ). (in /Users/mattiassiofjellvang/Projects/resecond/ - line 40, column 0)
```

This is my `behat.yml` file in root of my `laravel` project:

```
default:
    paths:
        features: app/tests/acceptance
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            goutte: ~
            base_url: http://my.app/api
```

This is my `composer.json`:

```
    "behat/behat": "2.5.*",
    "behat/mink": "1.5.*",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*"
```

Whats wrong? I am supposed to write more text, because SO thinks my post is mostly code. I disagree

Comment: Did you check what comes back with `Then print last response` or `Then show last response` before `Then I get a "200" response` line?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Mattias, checking the Users/mattiassiofjellvang/Projects/resecond/ - line 40 and put here, is possíble?

Comment: @Mattias - Insert `Then print last response` or `Then show last response` or `Then print response` before `Then I get a "200" response` to see what exactly comes back so that you can debug.